# How to pass Audio file from model to Template in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've just started out with Django and have tried making an audio player application website. I (admin) want to be able to upload audio files that visitors can listen to.

I've created a model for succesfully uploading a file, taking a input file name, and storing it in a media folder in within my app directory:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_player/media/audio_player/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my Template I then have a for loop set up to create list of audio players for every different audio track.:

```
<div class="container">
    {% for song in songs %}
        <audio controls id="player">
            <source src="{{ song.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Now this is where I've gotten stuck. The audio player appears accordingly, but you cannot play any audio. I've tried to check via Chromes DevTools and there the source, or src, is the correct file path to the files.

```
<source src="audio_player/media/audio_player/Song.wav" type="audio/wav">
```

I've been going crazy for the last day or so trying to figure out what is causing it not to work. I spent a lot of time trying to get it to source the correct path for the files but even though it seems to do that the files still can't be played.

I suspect that it could have something to to with passing the files into the template, from what I understand you should be able to pass a file as context right?

This is how my views are set up:

```
def ap(request):
    context = {
        "songs": Song.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, "audio_player/home.html",context)
```

Thankful for any help I can receive! Sorry for any eventual formatting errors and such...

Comment: Did you setup media in `settings.py` ?

Comment: As in edit MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL? No, since I'm using "upload_to='audio_player/media/audio_player/" I thought that I wouldn't need to specify them? Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Btw, I've tried some solutions using the MEDIA in settings that have helped fix similar problems for other users but none ended up working.

Comment: You are totally wrong, you only say `upload_to = "/audio_player/"`, then setup the media in `settings.py`

Comment: Thanks! Me being aware that I was totally wrong actually helped! Applied both MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in the correct way according to the Django docs and after some fiddling with the settings i got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by setting these in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

...and by adding this to my urls.py

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

...as well as changing my FileField Upload to

```
upload_to="audio_player/"
```

(Pretty much, just looking at the Django official docs again but being aware that I was not understanding things correctly and pretty much copying what it said straight up worked)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
    {% for song in songs %}
        <audio controls id="player">
            <source src="{% if song.audio_file %}{{ song.audio_file.url }}{% endif %}" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30846349)